# NullPointerException Error when trying to get a value from Another Bean in JSF

Tags: jsf, nullpointerexception

I've two backing beans:

- `Login`: a bean that validates the user login info (username and password) with database table.
- `Buss_Services`: another bean that performs some business services.

I need to get the user ID from the `Login` bean and use it inside the `Buss_Services`. It's stored in a String  property of `Login` and the `Buss_Services` needs this value to track the currently logged-in user and update the DB.

Here's the `Login` backing bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name="Login")
@SessionScoped
public class Login {
    private String loggedUserID;

    public Object logCB_action() {
        try {
            // ...
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(SQL);
            while (rs.next()) {
                if (rs.getString("USER_NAME").equals(uname)) {
                    if (rs.getString("USER_PW").equals(pword)) {

                     // Here, the user ID is set.
                    loggedUserID=rs.getString("USER_ID");// This line ...


                    System.out.println("Logged User (ID): "+ userID);

                        return ("displayApp");
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // ...
    }        

    public String getLoggedID() {
        // Here, the user ID is returned.
        String id = loggedUserID;
        return (id);
    }

}
```

Here's the `Buss_Services` backing bean which calls the `getLoggedID()` method:

```
@ManagedBean(name="Buss_Services")
@SessionScoped
public class Buss_Services {



    @ManagedProperty("#{Login}")
    private Login login;

    public void newEst_action() {
        // The following line throws NullPointerException.
        System.out.println("Logged User (ID): " + login.getLoggedID());       
    }

    // Getters/setters.
}
```

This is the stack trace which I get when I try to access the bussiness services page:

```
javax.faces.el.EvaluationException:
//C:/Users/Sultan09/AppData/Roaming/JDeveloper/system11.1.2.0.38.60.17/o.j2ee/drs/TheOCES/OCES.ViewControllerWebApp.war/App_Business_SerivesPG.jsf @68,140 action="#{backingBeanScope.App_BServPG_Bean.newEst_action}": java.lang.NullPointerException

at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.MethodExpressionMethodBinding.invoke(MethodExpressionMethodBinding.java:51)
at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXCommand.broadcast(UIXCommand.java:190)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:787)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1252)
at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._invokeApplication(LifecycleImpl.java:965)
at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:346)
at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:204)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:312)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:300)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
at oracle.adf.model.servlet.ADFBindingFilter.doFilter(ADFBindingFilter.java:173)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.webapp.rich.RegistrationFilter.doFilter(RegistrationFilter.java:121)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:468)
at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.activedata.AdsFilter.doFilter(AdsFilter.java:60)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:468)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl._doFilterImpl(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:293)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:199)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.TrinidadFilter.doFilter(TrinidadFilter.java:92)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter$1.run(JpsAbsFilter.java:111)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at oracle.security.jps.util.JpsSubject.doAsPrivileged(JpsSubject.java:313)
at oracle.security.jps.ee.util.JpsPlatformUtil.runJaasMode(JpsPlatformUtil.java:413)
at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.runJaasMode(JpsAbsFilter.java:94)
at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.doFilter(JpsAbsFilter.java:161)
at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsFilter.doFilter(JpsFilter.java:71)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
at oracle.dms.servlet.DMSServletFilter.doFilter(DMSServletFilter.java:136)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:27)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3715)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3681)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2277)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2183)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1454)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:209)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:178

 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at JavaView.backing.Buss_Services.newEst_action(Buss_Services.java:172)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.MethodExpressionMethodBinding.invoke(MethodExpressionMethodBinding.java:46)
    ... 44 more
```

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

---

**UPDATE** :
As per comments here and personal search on similar issues to the one stated here, the Problem is Finally solved ,thank god.
The solution was that I had to:

1. add the `<managed-property>` of login to the adfc-config.xml file .
2. more importantly , obtain the `loggedUserID` inside a `@PostConstruct` anotated method init() . Thanx everyone.

Comment: Instead of using `HtmlInputText`, why don't you use `String` directly.

Comment: I Tried that one , same problem unfortunately ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
System.out.println("Logged User (ID): " + login.get_final_logged_ID());
```

A `NullPointerException` on that line has as the only possible cause that `login` is `null`. Given the fact that the `@ManagedProperty` looks fine, this can have only one possible cause: the setter method `setLogin()` is broken. Make sure that it look exactly like this:

```
public void setLogin(Login login) {
    this.login = login;
}
```

and thus **not**

```
public void setLogin(Login login) {
    login = login;
}
```

or something else.

---

**Update** as per the comments:

> *As for the faces-config.xml , here's the thing , the Login and bussiness services beans,for their repective jsf pages , are defined as "backingBean" in the `<managed-bean-scope>`. In the java beans ,as u saw , I defined them sessionScoped.*

Finally, there is the cause of your problem. Configuration in `faces-config.xml` **overrides** all JSF2 annotations on the bean in question. You have apparently not configured the `<managed-property>` in the `faces-config.xml`. You have 2 options:

1. Remove the whole `<managed-bean>` configuration in `faces-config.xml`. The whole point of new JSF 2.x annotations like `@ManagedBean`, `@ManagedProperty`, etc is to *get rid* of verbose JSF 1.x style XML configuration.
2. Add a `<managed-property>` value of `#{Login}` to the `<managed-bean>` of `Buss_Services`.

   ```
   <managed-property>
       <property-name>login</property-name>
       <value>#{Login}</value>
   </managed-property>
   ```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem. You've several serious flaws in the design and code style.

- You should **not** reference `UIComponent`s as properties. Instead, you should reference its values. Keep the model as simple as possible and never use `UIComponent` unless you have a really valid reason. E.g.

  ```
  private String username;
  private String password;
  private Long userID;
  ```
- Your login validation method is inefficient. It seems to haul the entire users table from DB into Java's memory wherein you test every individual row. You should try to write and finetune the SQL query as much as possible so that it returns **exactly** the information you're looking for.

  ```
  statement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT id FROM Users WHERE username = ? AND password = MD5(?)");
  statement.setString(1, username);
  statement.setString(2, password);
  resultSet = statement.executeQuery();

  if (resultSet.next()) {
      userID = resultSet.getLong("id");
  }
  ```
- Your PHP-like code style fully contradicts the [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html#367). It makes the code harder to read and maintain by all other Java developers, such as the ones from who you expect answers when you post the code on the Internet, like here. Package names should be all lowercase. Underscores are only valid in constants, for all other names CamelCase should be used. Instance names (like managed bean names) should start with lowercase. Etcetera.

Comment: I double checked the setter and getter methods of the Login bean object for any probelm ,they seem fine , but I'm till getting the same erorr !!! . And great Thanks for the other great tips sir..

Comment: To be sure, this is the complete stacktrace? The **real** root cause is the bottommost part.

Comment: I've updated the post , complete stacktrace log is there. Hope u check it out.

Comment: Well, `login` is clearly `null` at that point. Is the `setLogin()` method ever invoked on bean's construction? Is the `@ManagedBean` annotation from the `javax.faces.bean` package? (and thus not `javax.annotation` package).

Comment: Answer to second question , yes it's from the faces.bean package. As for the the first question , i don't unerstand it clearly . U mean I should call setLogin(login) inside the newEst_action() method where i get the NPE line ? even though i just tried that too, same error !

Comment: JSF should have called `setLogin()` method because you have a `@ManagedProperty`. You need to check if that method is called. Put a debug breanpoint on it or add a `System.out.println()`/`logger.debug()` line.

Comment: sorry balusC , could u specify where i put logger.debug()? in setLogin() or inside newEst_action() ? Plus , the logger object is from imported class or what??

Comment: about the logger.debug() line,how to declare the logger object so i can use it ?!!

Comment: That's a whole subject apart which is unrelated to your current question. If you aren't already using a logger, forget it for now and just use sysout or debugger.

Comment: ok , so I'll use the System.out.println(). what should i print here ?in other words what to put inside the .println(""+?)

Comment: The variable of interest, `login`. It seems that the concept of "debugging" is completely new to you. I suggest you to learn more about that. Debugging basically boils down to tracking the code execution line by line and check which methods are all invoked and which variables are all in the stack, etc. It will result in very useful information as to what's happening during code execution.

Comment: the System.out.println(login); line I just added doesn't seem to print anything in the webLogicServer Log tab .

Comment: Okay, that explains it. The `@ManagedProperty` is thus simply never been invoked. The only sensible cause for this can be is that `@ManagedBean` is not from `javax.faces.bean` package. But in your case the problem seems to be deeper. What JSF impl/version exactly are you using? What Weblogic version exactly are you using? Did you redefine the beans in `faces-config.xml` or not?

Comment: Ok , 1) JSF version is 2.0 implemented in a fusion web application (ADF) framework. 2) WebLogicServer is 11gR1 . 3) As for the faces-config.xml , here's the thing , the Login and bussiness services beans,for their repective jsf pages , are defined as "backingBean" in the <managed-bean-scope> . In the java beans ,as u saw , I defined them sessionScoped.

Comment: OK mr. BalusC I went with the second option , added <managed-property> in the place u said. I get syntex error in the <value> tag that states "EL token"login" is unknown" ?!! any idea ?

Comment: It has to be the exact managed bean name of the bean you'd like to inject. It's case sensitive. By the way, I've never seen this particular error message before. This sounds more like an IDE-specific error. You can also just ignore it altogether and just run the code (JDeveloper often pretends to be smarter than it is).

Comment: by The way I was referring to the "adfc-config.xml " in the comment I explained the beans scopes earlier . The faces-config.xml doesn't contain any info about the beans at all.

Comment: OK mr.BalusC after i set " the exact name", the NPE is no more , the app wroks fine , BUT the result from the printLn in the newEst_action() prints "Logged user (ID) : null "!!

Comment: That's a different problem and most likely caused because you used for no reason `HtmlInputText` instead of `String` or `Long` to hold the value.

Comment: Yeah I agree it's difinitely different because thanx to your precious help , the app doesn't show the NPE anymore. But i also followed  your advice and went to string based value that will store the value entered by the user in the HTML fields. so now the method would return the string property ,still getting it null! even though the value is initialized in the Try Block...

Comment: Apparently the login bean is not session scoped. By the way, why are you using the old `faces-config.xml` approach to manage beans instead of annotations? If you did this because the annotations doesn't work, then this indicates that there's really many more wrong in your webapp.

Comment: The login bean is session scoped as stated in the code above in the post!! As for the faces-config.xml, it doesn't have any managed beans tags at all, all are in "adfc-config.xml" file. I don't manually set them up there , Jdeveloper sets them up automatically everytime i create a new jsf page that has backing bean associated with it .

Answer (score 0):

Ok NullPointerException is a very general class of errors which have nothing to do with jsf or your db access layer etc in particular. And as far as i can see from the stacktrace it is being thrown from inside of newEst_action function for which you have not provided any code. Go to the specific line in that function i.e. 172 and see if you are doing something like

```
 myObject.doSomething()
```

without checking that the object could be null,it could throw NPE if myObject is null, so do something like

```
if (myObject!=null)
    myObject.doSomething()
```

Comment: This is the Line (172) again : 
    System.out.println("Logged User   (ID): "+login.get_final_logged_ID());

Comment: the .get_final_logged_ID() should return the value of logged_user_ID...  To further clarify , The Logged_user_ID (HTML inputtext) is set a value when a valid username/password comb is accepted , in the same code block I mean. check the Login calss again , hope it clears it more.

Comment: @user1092784 oK i think we can boil it down to login is null and there can be many reasons for it... one of obvious one which is can see is you dont have a setLogin() method for the managed property. Try adding public void setLogin(Login login){this.login=login;}

Comment: @ChinPing I've added both a get and setLogin methods , still the same error !!

Answer (score 0):

Please check if your ManagedProperty `login` isnt null, when you print the id.

and try  `@ManagedProperty(value = "#{Login}")` !

Comment: i don't understand why it become null ? because it is sessionScoped, that means when another jsf page backing bean want to get a property value from it ,it should be ok, right?? plus , the (business services) page will be accessed after the login page.

Comment: see edited, i think the bean is null, not the `get_final_logged_ID()`